# Geoserver Cascading WMS, Wrong Projection

Tags: geoserver, wms

I configured a geoserver store with an external WMS. I used the following WMS url

http://www2.dmsolutions.ca/cgi-bin/mswms_gmap?VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Once I saved the store, Geoserver listed the layers on the screen. I clicked the "Publish" link of the "DEMO" layer and I saved it with the default options.

When I display the layer preview, the layer has a wrong projection and is repeated many times.
Here you can see the image:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336018/geoserver-cascading-wms-wrong-projection

The projection of the layer seems to be wrong. I tried to force to another projection or to keep the native one but results are not better.

Have you any ideas about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is due to the projection of the source WMS service.

The service returns projection as 42304. Most problably, the cause of the issue is the EPSG code of 42304, which not an official EPSG code, according to [this discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/EPSG-42304-gt-EPSG-3978-or-3979-td4228522.html) on the Mapserver mailing list.